# Returning an object with map.call

Tags: javascript

This works:

```
evaluate(function() {
    return Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.container .title'), function(e) {
        return e.querySelector('.title').textContent;
    });
}
evaluate(function() {
    return Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.container .title a'), function(e) {
        return e.querySelector('.title a').href;
    });
}
evaluate(function() {
    return Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.container img'), function(e) {
        return e.querySelector('img').src;
    });
}
```

.. however, I want to return all results as a single object, but this doesn't work because I can't figure how to get the index:

```
evaluate(function() {
    return Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.container'), function(e) {
        var data = {};
        data[index].title = e.querySelector('.title').textContent;
        data[index].link = e.querySelector('.title').href;
        data[index].image = e.querySelector('img').src;
        // return all results in a single object with each containing title, link and image
        return data; 
    });
}
```

This is the complete function:

```
new Nightmare(
        .goto('https://www.example.com')
        .insert('form[id="gbqf"] input[id="gbqfq"]', 'keyword here')
        .click('form[id="gbqf"] button[id="gbqfb"]')
        .wait('.sh-sr__shop-result-group')
        .visible('.sh-sr__shop-result-group')
        .evaluate(function() {
            return Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.sh-sr__shop-result-group .psli'), function(data, e) {
                data.push({
                    title: e.querySelector('.pslmain h3').textContent,
                    thumb: e.querySelector('.pslimg img').src,
                    link: e.querySelector('.pslmain h3 a').href,
                    price: e.querySelector('.pslline .price').textContent,
                    stars: e.querySelector('span._Ezj div').getAttribute('aria-label'),
                    ratings: e.querySelector('a.shop__secondary.sh-rt__product').textContent,
                    //features: e.querySelector('._Lqc .shop__secondary _MAj').innerHTML,
                    //description: e.querySelector('._Lqc').textContent
                });
                return data;
            });
        })
        .end()
        .then(function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.error('Search failed:', error);
        });
```

Comment: Note, `.textContent` is not a function, remove `()` at `data[index].title = e.querySelector('.title').textContent()`

Comment: @guest271314 I don't have the index value to create the objects.

Comment: You did not define the `index` parameter at `.map()` callback `(e, index)`. Why do you need to define an `index` property at returned object? The returned array should be in order of `document.querySelectorAll('.container')`

Comment: first example are 3 array and not one object ?

Comment: what is the shape of the final object ?

Comment: In your first example, you're selection looks all wrong. For example, you're trying to select the first `img` inside each `img`, which  is impossible. The others are technically possible, but somehow I doubt you have a `.title a` inside each `.title a`. Even if you did, they'd be selected in the original selection.

Comment: The `data` in your callback will be each element in the Array, which doesn't have a `.push()` method. You should just be returning the object. `return { title: ..., thumb: ...}`

Comment: ...like this: https://jsfiddle.net/j33dgdg3/ So the result is an Array of Objects where for each element found by `querySelectorAll`, there will be a new object in the new Array.

Comment: @squint Your fiddle. :) If you could post that as answer, I'd accept it.

Comment: You can go ahead and accept @aeid's answer if you want since it is correct. Only difference is that he's replicating the functionality of `.map()` using `.reduce()`. But in practice I'd use `.map()` since it's designed specifically for this purpose.

Comment: ...also note that the new `Array.from` method, which is used for converting an Array-like object to an Array, allows you to pass a callback that behaves like `.map()`. So, `return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.sh-sr__shop-result-group .psli'), function(data, e) { return { /*the object*/ }; })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what shape you want your final object to be . but this seems as close to first implementation as possible .

```
function evaluate(containerName){
  return Array.prototype.reduce.call(document.querySelectorAll(containerName), function(acc , e){
    acc.push({
      title: e.querySelector('.title').textContent, 
      link: e.querySelector('.title a').href,
      image: e.querySelector('img').src
    }) 
    return acc 
  } , [] )
}
```

returns an array of objs corresponding to containers indexs .

Comment: You're going to throw an error after the first iteration. You seem to be trying to use `.reduce()` in place of `.map()`. Why not just use `.map()`?

Comment: I don't think that it will I will test it , using reduce because he wanted a single object .

Comment: Your callback has no return value, so `acc` will be `undefined` after the first iteration. Also, your object has a syntax error with the `=`. Your accumulator is an Array, and so it looks like you're creating an Array of Objects, which is what `.map()` is designed for.

Comment: @squint thanks .  I think that accomplishes what he wants though .

Comment: Yes, but again you could use `.map()`. Not that your updated code is wrong, but `.map()` is a specialized "reduce" function designed to build a new Array of items equal in length to the original.

Comment: @3zzy: I can't tell if you're referring to aeid's answer or my jsFiddle link above. Anyway, you were close. Just needed to return the object instead of pushing it.

Answer (score 0):

You may iterate over document.querySelectorAll('.container') before the map and build an array with indexes, like:

```
var kvArray = [{index:0, value:document.querySelectorAll('.container')[0]}, {index:2, value:20}, {index:3, value: 30}];
var reformattedArray = kvArray.map(function(obj){ 
   var rObj = {};
   rObj[obj.key] = obj.valor;
   return rObj;
});
```

And use your object key to access the rObj correspondent place.

Anyway from the docs, seems to be that you can get the index from the callback function. Please take a look to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=control

```
var new_array = arr.map(callback[, thisArg])
Parameters

callback
Function that produces an element of the new Array, taking three arguments:

currentValue
The current element being processed in the array.
index
The index of the current element being processed in the array.
array
The array map was called upon.
thisArg
Optional. Value to use as this when executing callback.
```

Hope it helps.